# How to define constant for key which is defined inside array using Php?

Tags: php

I have created array inside a class using constant and assigned values to that array by key,
value pair so I want to create const for key which will be define outside array for example

```
const for_a_value= foo::arrayOfvalues[0].key
```

So in future if I want to change key name I need to change at one place only so how to create this

```
 <?php  

    class foo {

        const arrayOfvalues = [
            'a' => 'text for  a',
            'b' => 'text for b',
            'c' => 'text for c'

        ]; 
        const for_avalue= foo::arrayOfvalues[0];  //create constant for a
        const for_bvalue= foo::arrayOfvalues[1];  //create constant for b
        const for_cvalue= foo::arrayOfvalues[2];  //create constant for c

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: Why not `const for_avalue= foo::arrayOfvalues['a'];`?

Comment: Why do you need the constants both as an array and as individual values?

Comment: You cannot initialize a const with another variable, as const would be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @JustinT. as  per requirement  it must be  [0]

Comment: What if you remove the `b` constant - do you have to renumber all of the `arrayOfvalues[2]` settings?

Comment: @Manpreet, actually requiremet is assign  another name for the key with the help of constant.so how to do this?

Comment: Do you have another array, of which key needs to be assigned from const? Can you update your question to explain this

Comment: @Manpreet,i require constant for array keys ,I am not working with another array